# how does a symbol table be in case of method overloading in c#

Tags: c#, methods, overloading, symbol-table

How is a **symbol table** represented in method overloading?

Comment: Can you add more detail around this question? Does this question make sense if we use an other type? For now i read it as "How is type T  represented in method overloading?" and the answer is "Yes like any overload method have the same name but other parameter like `class Test
{
    static void Foo(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(int x)");
    }
    
    static void Foo(string y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(string y)");
    }`"

Answer (score 2):

The compilers that I am familiar with do it by synthesizing a unique name for each overload based on the given name and the types of the arguments.

Say for example you have three overloads for a function, MyFunc:

```
void MyFunc(int arg1);
void MyFunc(double arg1);
void MyFunc(int arg1, int arg2);
```

Internally, the compiler might call them

```
MyFunc$i4
MyFunc$d8
MyFunc$i4$i4
```

or similar, where the `$` delimiter here is some character that isn't allowed in user-defined symbol names, and the suffixes are made up of short-hand code symbols for basic data types (i4 = 4-byte signed integer, d8 = double, and so on).

(The scheme I show here is just something I made up to illustrate the principle. To see how it's actually done, google `compiler name mangling`).